# changing specific data from div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div like this:

```
<div id="something" data-tip="tipeofdata"></div>
```

Then I want to change that data-tip with Jquery. I was trying like this:

```
$('#something').data('tip') = 'newdata';
```

But doesnt work. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong syntax:

```
$('#something').data('tip') = 'newdata';
```

Should be:

```
$('#something').data('tip','newdata');
```

But that will change data object property value, not DOM node attribute

To change attribute on DOM node, you need to use:

```
$('#something').attr('data-tip','newdata');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#something').attr('data-tip','newdata');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. This is what I am using and it works fine:

```
$('#something').attr('data-tip', 'newdata');
```

But also you can try the following:

```
$('#something').data('tip', 'newdata');
```

I have not tried that, but I suppose will work.